# Adding method to event by casting delegate?

Tags: c#

I come from a Java background and am currently learning c#.

I understand that when one wants to subscribe a method to a event, one does it like the following:

```
button.Click += HandleClick;

void HandleClick (object sender, EventArgs e) {
   button.Text = string.Format (count++ + " clicks!"); 
}
```

However, one can seem to write this like the following to:

```
button.Click += delegate {button.Text = string.Format (count++ + " clicks!");};
```

Are we casting the method to a delegate? I thought the event wants a method to be subscribed to it? What exactly is happing above?

Answer (score 3):

> Are we casting the method to a delegate?

Well, you're not casting - but you're using a *method group conversion* to convert a method name into a delegate.

> I thought the event wants a method to be subscribed to it?

No, an event needs a *delegate* to subscribe to it (or unsubscribe from it). You can create a delegate instance *from* a method, either with the code you've given or more explicitly:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(HandleClick);
```

Or even separate the two:

```
EventHandler handler = HandleClick; // Method group conversion
button.Click += handler;            // Event subscription
```

... or you can create a delegate instance from an anonymous function (either an anonymous method or a lambda expression).

See my [article on delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The `delegate` keyword is creating a new anonymous method.  A delegate is then (implicitly) created that refers to that anonymous method, and that delegate is added as one of the delegates for that event.